# Getting JSON from the Sharepoint API with $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

By default the data returned from the Sharepoint API is encoded in XML, but I am looking to get JSON back. I am using jquery to make the ajax call. I believe this should be accomplished by passing a header along with the ajax request like

```
{ "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
```

I have tried doing this two different ways.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url/to/web/api",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
})
.done(function(data) {
})
```

and

```
function setHeaders(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json; odata=verbose')
}

$.ajax({
    url: "url/to/web/api",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: setHeaders
})
.done(function(data) {
})
```

Both of these have returned XML. I have successfully gotten JSON back when making the call from postman and passing the header in. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What Sharepoint version?

Comment: It is 2007, but I am using 2013 documentation. The postman call worked so I think the setup is correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77804/sharepoint-2007-jsonp-web-services) there are no native JSON-emitting endpoints in SharePoint 2007.

The SOAP-based .asmx web services only emit XML responses.

Note this question was specifically about SharePoint 2007, which was only available as an on-premises environment.

Comment: The situation may have changed.  Scheetz's first method using the "headers:" parameter is working fine for me in SharePoint Online today.

Comment: I see that now.  If you give me the go, I will delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `dataType` to your request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url/to/web/api", // <-- also, you had a dot here
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}
    dataType: "json" // <-- right here
})
.done(function(data) {
})
```

**Update:** I think your real issue was that little typo (dot instead of comma).

Comment: Ah sorry. I was typing the answer quickly before I left work to beat rush hour (can't copy and paste from a virtual desktop). I can guarantee there are no syntax errors causing the issue.

Comment: Have you tried the `dataType` property to your `ajax` request?